# Mac OS X Server (on home network) causing windows machines to have flakey wireless connection

Tags: osx-server

I just setup OS X Server on my spare macbook pro on my home network.  I turned on timemachine so I could backup my macbook air over the wifi to the MBP's external drive.  That seemed to work well.

However: ever since, my old windows 7 laptop has had very flakey access to the internet via wifi.

When I turn OS X server off, the windows machine can connect to wifi and interent easily.

All I want is a cheap way to backup to my external hdd over wifi ... any hints on how to fix this?  (I'm not a superuser on mac, obviously, but I am a computer scientist from way back...)